# ANTLR, how to convert BNF,EBNF data in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, bnf, ebnf

I have to generate parser of CSV data. Somehow I managed to write BNF, EBNF for CSV data but I don't know how to convert this into an ANTLR grammar (which is a parser generator). For example, in EBNF we write:

```
[{header entry}newline]newline
```

but when I write this in ANTLR to generate a parser, it's giving an error and not taking brackets. I am not expert in ANTLR can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

> hi , i have to generate parser of CSV data ...

In most languages I know, there already exists a decent 3rd party CSV parser. So, chances are that you're reinventing the wheel.

> For Example in EBNF we wrire [{header entry}newline]newline

The equivalent in ANTLR would look like this:

```
((header entry)* newline)? newline
```

In other words:

```
                 | (E)BNF | ANTLR
-----------------+--------+------
'a' zero or once | [a]    | a?
'a' zero or more | {a}    | a*
'a' once or more | a {a}  | a+
```

Note that you can group rules by using parenthesis (sub-rules is what they're called):

```
'a' 'b'+
```

matches: `ab`, `abb`, `abbb`, `...`, while:

```
('a' 'b')+
```

matches: `ab`, `abab`, `ababab`, `...`

Comment: thanks this will really help me while converting EBNF into ANTLR

Comment: hi bart, where do we use {} brackets in ANTLR . 
For Example
field
 : ( f=QUOTED
   | f=UNQUOTED
   | // nothing
   )
  { $line::fields.add(($f == null) ? "" : $f.text); }
 ;

Comment: @Hammad, you use `{ ... }` in your rules to embed code. If you have a specific question about it, I recommend you create a new question instead of asking it in the comments here. Good luck!